# Как запретить ходить по каталогам на сайте

Tags: php, веб-программирование, .htaccess

Всех приветствую,есть сайт как запретить пользователям ходить по каталогам ну например открыл сайт попал на `index.php` и допустим он ввел в адресную строку `index.php/images` и допустим его перебросило на страницу с ошибкой можно так сделать ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант можно спрятать важные файлы в отдельную директорию. Можно реализовать запрос на ввод пароля к примеру. 
Но выше верно сказали, копайте в сторону .htaccess

**Вот вам пару ссылок на эту тему, с примерами и документацией:**

[Что такое .htaccess и с чем его есть?](https://hostiq.ua/wiki/htaccess/#4_1)

[25 Правил которые вам лучше знать об .htaccess](http://blogerator.org/page/fajl-primery-htaccess-redirekt-dostup)

[Старая добрая вики, для общего развития](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B_.htaccess)

Comment: я б добавил еще инфу по роутам ( например как это реализуют это фреймворки)..

Answer (score 0):

В папке к которой хочешь запретить доступ размести файл .htaccess

```
Deny from all
```